# SQL Server 2008 R2 error "The program or feature cannot start or run due to incompatibity with 64-bit versions of Windows."

Tags: installation, windows-server-2008-r2, 64-bit, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm installing SQL Server 2008 R2 using a DVD that says `32/64`onto a Windows Server 2008 R2 server. I want to install the 64-bit version of SQL Server 2008 R2. I am installing SQL Server with the failover cluster feature enabled and configured. However, when I run the SQL Server 2008 R2 setup file I get the following error.

> The version of this file is not
>   compatible with the version of Windows
>   you're running. Check your computer's
>   system information to see whether you
>   need an x86 (32-bit) or x64 (64-bit)
>   version of the program, and then
>   contact the software publisher.

When I look at the Event Viewer I see the following error:

> The program or feature
>   "\??\D:\setup.exe" cannot start or run
>   due to incompatibity with 64-bit
>   versions of Windows. Please contact
>   the software vendor to ask if a 64-bit
>   Windows compatible version is
>   available.

The SQL Server 2008 R2 installer is 32/64 bit and of course Windows Server 2008 R2 is 64 bits. What could be preventing the installation from proceeding?

Comment: I can confirm that SQL 2008 R2 x64 works on W2008R2 x64, we've got that setup here.  Have you tried re-installing Windows?

Comment: Nope, But I tested the installer on other machines and got the same error. When the machine is 32 bits it just opens a prompt and closes it in a second, when the machine is 64 bits it throws that error up

Comment: Check the ISO of the SQL Server installation and make sure there is a folder called x64. If there is, try running the setup file found in that folder.

Comment: There is. The folder is in there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to Work this around.

I found this pre req on installing SQL on Cluster.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189910.aspx

under: Other Software Considerations

There's this pre reqs:

> SQL Server Setup support files. You
>   can install these files by running
>   SqlSupport.msi located on your SQL
>   Server 2008 R2 installation media.

I Located that file On:

```
D:\1033_ENU_LP\x64\Setup\sql2008support\sqlsupport.msi
```

That installed the setup on the machine.
Then I ran the setup from the All Programs Menu and after that pointed the disk when asked.

I Noticed that after installing SQL the Setup begins to work normally. This must have happened by some weird pre-req, that the setup must have installed for me.